# Testing angular2 dart component

Tags: angular, dart

I wrote a component and want to test it.

How can I write a test from component? Is there any test framwork for angular2dart?

Comment: I added another link with a test example.

Comment: AngularDart will also be providing pageObjects for testing https://youtu.be/vAUUOwBJetg?t=7m26s

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [test](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test) package with the experimental testing implementation https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/blob/master/lib/testing_experimental.dart
I haven't seen examples and I haven tried it myself yet.

See also https://github.com/matanlurey/angular2_api_examples/tree/master/testing/test

I found a few tests using it in https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=testbed and https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/tree/master/lib/src/modules/testing/test