# Angular2 Dart TestComponentBuilder fails with "No provider for TestComponentBuilder!"

Tags: unit-testing, angular, dart

I try to write a simple component test in Angular2 Dart and get stuck at `No provider for TestComponentBuilder!` when I run them with `pub run test -j1 -p dartium`

My test looks like this:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'test-cmp',
    template: '<textarea \n\n</textarea>')
class TestComponent {}


void main() {
  initAngularTests();

  ngTest('New component test', (TestComponentBuilder testComponentBuilder) async {
    final testComponent = await testComponentBuilder.createAsync(TestComponent);
    testComponent.detectChanges();

    print(testListComponent);
    //expect(to be done...);
  });
}
```

Ok I now also ported the example to the mentioned testing library. Now I get `No precompiled component TestComponent found`

```
void main() {
  reflector.reflectionCapabilities = new ReflectionCapabilities();

  test('New event list component is empty', () async {
    print('test start');
    var testBed = new NgTestBed<TestComponent>();
    var fixture = await testBed.create();
    // expect...
  }
```

Comment: I think testing is moving to `TestBed` (not sure) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590390/testing-angular2-dart-component

Comment: ohh no I am getting crazy, try to find the right way to do tests but there seems to be good documentation missing

Comment: Right, there are no docs yet. Seems to be still experimental.

Comment: Just adding the link to the GH issue for people coming here: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_api_examples/issues/2